# KO Foreach binding not updating iterating list

Tags: knockout.js

I have a table that is being created from a list. I have a button that adds to that list. This is real simple but cant seem to find out what I am missing. Here is my code:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Remove</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: names">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="Remove" width="20px" height="20px" src="/Content/Images/delete.png" data-bind="click: $parent.removeValue">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
  <h2>
    <span data-bind="text: addValueError"></span>
  </h2>
  <label for="addValue">Add Value</label>
  <input id="addValue" type="text" data-bind="value: newValue" />
  <img id="add" width="20px" height="20px" src="/Content/Images/add.png" data-bind="click: addNewValue">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var model= new Model($('#someDiv')[0], data);
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Model($id, data) {
    var self = this;
self.names = ko.observablearray(['1','2','3']);
self.removeValue = function(){
//remove
}
self.addValueError = ko.observable();
self.newValue = ko.observable();
self.addNewValue = function(){
if (self.newValue () != null && self.newValue ().length > 0) {
            self.Names().push(self.newValue ());
            self.newValue ('');
            self.addValueError ('');
        } else {
            self.addValueError ('Please provide a value to add.');
        }
};

ko.applyBindings(self, $id);
}
```

When I add a value, it is added to the names list but it is not updated in the table. Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to show you JavaScript code.

Comment: Show us your view model? ANd also show your add to array code.

Comment: There you go. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist off, I woudnt call apply bindings in your viewmodel constructor.

Pass your instance of model into it.

I would remove the != null for your truth check n the add function because you never have it set to null but from the looks it might be undefined or ''

```
Names
```

should be

```
names
```

Try calling push like this

```
self.names.push(self.newValue);
```

You need the observable to notify for the view to update so dont push directly to the underlying array.

Comment: Changing self.names().push to self.names.push worked! Thanks so much.